# SSH Key doesn't work

Tags: ssh

I'm having a problem with ssh keys on my server. Whenever I try to connect, it tells me this (I want to use the key to authenticate myself instead of typing password, but it still asks me for password after.) From my understanding from other articles, it asks me for my password because the private key authentication failed or something? I ran `ssh -vvv user@ip` and got this:

```
$ ssh -vvv user@ip
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug2: resolving "ip" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ip [ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ip:22 as 'user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/Aericio/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/Aericio/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ip
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:hTCFRXSL6Pn2ahO8AzocQsLS+VZP26OnZm/WvOWqq1I
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/Aericio/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/Aericio/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ip
debug1: Host 'ip' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/Aericio/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_ecdsa
Enter passphrase for key '/home/Aericio/.ssh/id_ecdsa':
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: ECDSA SHA256:/nMfW17zQ9zoH1UCzlSmLWtN4Mh/ST62SE5sB9B7D24
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@ip's password:
```

My configuration file in sshd_config is:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 60
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding no
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive no
#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

I've been trying to do other thing. Whenever I disabled the set `passwordauthentication` and `pam` to no, it tells me:

```
$ ssh user@ip
Enter passphrase for key '/home/Aericio/.ssh/id_ecdsa':
Permission denied (publickey).
```

FYI: I am using cygwin64 to use ssh. Thanks.

Comment: Check that `.ssh/authorized_keys` **for your userid _on the server_** exists, is owned and writable only by your id, is not garbled or misformatted, and contains the publickey exactly matching your privatekey. (If necessary get the publickey from the privatekey with `ssh-keygen -y`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the relevant part of your log file:

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/Aericio/.ssh/id_ecdsa
Enter passphrase for key '/home/Aericio/.ssh/id_ecdsa':
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: ECDSA SHA256:/nMfW17zQ9zoH1UCzlSmLWtN4Mh/ST62SE5sB9B7D24
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
```

SSH found one key file (id_ecdsa) - it asked you for its password then relayed it to the destination server. The destination server didn't trust your key and ssh moved on to using the next authentication method.

What you need to do is copy the public key over to the destination server into the `authorized_keys` file, most easily with something like the following:

```
ssh-copy-id <user>@<destination server>
```

If you have more than one key or have one specific identity to copy over, you can add `-i .ssh/id_ecdsa.pub` to the command

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. I was generating the files on the system instead of my local system at first... thought that wouldn't change anything.

Comment: > If you have more than one key or have one specific identity to copy over, you can add -i .ssh/id_ecdsa.pub to the command.

Does this mean if I want to give another person access to the system also, I add their private key to the public?

Comment: To add another person, you log in to that person on the source server, then create their ssh-key via `ssh-keygen` and copy it over to the destination server via `ssh-copy-id <destination server>`. That's the easiest and most transparent option.

Comment: You definitely create the key pair at your /their work station, not at the server, then you add the pubkey to .ssh/authorized_keys on the server.